# How to redirect a user to previous URL after submitting a form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a questionnarie. As administrator, you are able to edit questions as you are viewing them.

A page with the questions can have following url:

```
http://localhost/Survey/DisplayQuestions/2/1
```

When the administrator pushes the "Edit" link, an Edit view is displayed. When the administrator pushes "Save", i would like to redirect him to the previous site, which in this example would be:

```
http://localhost/Survey/DisplayQuestions/2/1
```

How can i accomplish this?

The Edit action looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Question question)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Question.Attach(question);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(question, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.category_id = new SelectList(db.Category, "category_id", "category_name", question.category_id);
        ViewBag.type_code = new SelectList(db.Question_Type, "type_code", "type_description", question.type_code);
        return View(question);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a controller "Survey" and action "DisplayQuestions". What you basically need is to return Admin back to this action. But, as far as I see DisplayQuestions recieves some paramerers (2/1).. Since, you have to put the same parameters to restore the same state.

I believe that Question object, contains all required info for that.. If not, it have to be extended.

I don't know how your model looks like, so I assume that Question contains Id, QuestionId field (just for intance)

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Question question)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do something..

            return RedirectToAction("DisplayQuestions", "Survey", new { id = question.Id, questionId = question.questionId});
        }

        // do something else..     
        return View(question);
    }
```

That would correctly redirect to DisplayQuestions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first parameter in DisplayQuestions is the category which the question belongs to. I can get this from the question entity. The second parameter is the page number, because i use paging to display 2 rows questions at a time. The page number is not in the questions entity?

Comment: once again - you decided your design. provide all required input into Edit POST method and perform right redirect. I can write you exact code, but i thing I said anought to get the point.

Comment: I have made a ViewModel of my Question entity. It has a String RefUrl. I make it as a hidden field, and use javascript's document.referrer to update the value of this field. then i can use it my in controller.